# How can we filter the google calendar events with attendee name

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there any way to get the calendar events specifically with attendee name.

I have checked the API for this,

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

If I pass event name with q='abc'. I able to get the matched event.

But particularly I want to pass the attendee name to get the event from calendar.

With the above API, I suspect we might get by using  privateExtendedProperty or sharedExtendedProperty request parameters  (propertyName=Name)  but I didn't get. I stuck while passing the values and get the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search for google calendar events is free text.

> Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties. Optional. (string)

Which means that you add the text you want to search for and it will search for that value in all of the fields its designed to search.  You cant specifiy that it should check only `items(attendees%252Femail)` for example

[example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=primary&q=xxx%2540gmail.com&fields=items(attendees%252Femail)&_h=10&)  Just add the persons email address you want to search for then you will have to process it again on your end to ensure that its actually the attended thats set and not some other field.

Comment: can we check the attendee and summary same time with this q filed?

Comment: it is a free text field google says it checks all the fields.   If it doesn't check that field you should file a feature request suggesting they add it.

Comment: Is it possible to filter based on the requestId of the conferenceData?  Say  we have created an event with this request ID.   "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
     "requestId": "1qwerty1",