# Query text for organizer email address in calendar events list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've been struggling with a specific requirement where I need to return all events in a users primary calendar where that user is the organiser of the event to either delete the events or transfer them all to another user.

I can get all events in a users primary calendar regardless of the owner and then loop through them to pick out the events where organizer.email = user@domain.com but this is not the most efficient way of doing it. I would expect the api to be able to return results only where the organizer = user using the query string as per https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

```
var events = Calendar.Events.list(calID, {
      maxResults: 250,
      pageToken: PageToken,
      q: 'email:"user@domain.com"'
    });
```

I have used q: 'email:"user@domain.com"' which returns all events where the email address is the creator, organizer or attendee.
I have tried a few variations like q: 'organizer.email:" etc but it would be great if there were some documentation like there is for other apis that can use query strings.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-groups

I'd expect to be able to specify a query along the lines of q: "organizerEmail:user@domain.com" which will only return the events where this user is the organizer.

Does anybody know what the query string would be to achieve this?

I have also asked this on the Google Calendar API Google groups forum.

Comment: I think the API documentation you linked to is correct and it literally accepts "search terms" and nothing more, i.e. `q` only accepts values, not keys.  From brief experimentation, I don't believe it is tokenizing and parsing `q` like you want. It doesn't understand "key:value", just "value".  There is probably another solution to your problem that doesn't require `q`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505656/11599789